# Configuring ASP.NET web site in IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, asp.net

I have installed IIS and .NET 4.0 on Windows Server 2003.

I have a web ready website that that targets .NET 4.0 and have updated the default website home directory to map to the website's directory.

When I visit the website in a web browser (localhost, localhost:80), I get a 404 error (File or directory not found).

Here is the IP address so you can see for yourself. http://72.45.244.92/

How do I get my ASP.NET 4.0 website to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install IIS **before** installing .NET 4.0. If IIS is installed after .NET 4.0, you need to use command prompt and run the `aspnet_regiis` tool located in the .net 4.0 directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you install ASP.NET in the using the Add or Remove Programs dialog box on the Control Panel?
2. In IIS Manager: did you allow the ASP.NET Web Service Extension?

See this [Technet article about Installing ASP.NET (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/7ecaa5f3-5499-4887-8c9d-00aba71125df.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: I had to allow the ASP.NET Web Service Extension. Thanks!

Comment: This wasn't exactly what was wrong with my installation, but it pointed me in the right direction.  I had to allow ASP.NET in Web Service Extensions (Start > IIS Manager > [server](local computer) > Web Service Extensions > ASP.NET(2 or 4) > Allow.  Thanks for the link!